# Sonata Admin Bundle custom repository `find()` method

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I've just installed **Sonata Admin Bundle**, and the thing is, I have a custom repository for one of my entities with overriden `find()` method. It looks like this (there's more in it, but it's irrelevant):

```
public function find($id)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('blogArticle')
        ->select('blogArticle')
        ->where('blogArticle.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getSingleResult();
}
```

And it works perfectly fine for project. However, when I try to edit it via **Sonata Dashboard**, edit action produces error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

This happens because **Sonata** passes array `['id' => 1]` instead of simple integer value, like I do with `getRepository()->find(1)` method.

I could write a kludge for a repo to handle this, but it's obviously not an option. Maybe someone knows how to change that behaviour of **Sonata**, or else?

Comment: Would it be ok to change `->setParameter('id', $id['id'])`?

Comment: @ihsan That's a kludge. For OP: why would changing the behaviour of a vendor bundle be more graceful than handling different formats passed to a function you have better control over?

Comment: It's strange, an array should be passed to a `findBy()` function, not to `find()`...

Comment: Can you also point to which file/line in Sonata which is passing it this way? I can't tell you how to change its behaviour or override particular parts until I know which parts you're referring to. It may even warrant a PR. Your traceroute should indicate this.

Comment: I agree with Jean. It's just wrong. Also, I absolutely don't want to rewrite something in vendors. What I really want, is to find repo method or argument handling the **right** way.

Comment: What is the role of this `find()` function? It looks like it only makes the standard request.

Comment: I've mentioned, that there was more in it, but it's irrelevant. I use query hint there to set Gedmo TranslationWalker - but the problem is exactly in `setParameter()`.